# Failed to Authenticate with JSON | Google Apis

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

I have created a new project in GSuite and I am not able to authenticate. The scopes in the domain-wide delegation are the same as the old project. I am able to pass OAuth with the old app.

Project key from last year:

```
"access_token": "token",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "token_type": "Bearer"
```

New Created project key:

```
 "error": "unauthorized_client",
  "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested."
```